# AngularJS - Dynamic table headers from MongoDb jagged data

Tags: angularjs

**I have a jagged data from a MongoDb collection like this:**

> ```
> $scope.data = [ 
>     { "fieldA": "value-a",
>       "fieldB": "value-b"
>     }, { 
>       "fieldA": "value-a", 
>       "fieldB": "value-b", 
>       "fieldC": "value-c"  
>     }]
> ```

**Using  ...**

> ```
>     angular.forEach(data, function(item){
>         $scope.colHeaders.push(item. ?????????)
>     });
> ```

**How can I get the field names as column headers and avoid duplication?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Object.keys (Not tested):

```
angular.forEach(data, function(item){
    $scope.colHeaders.push(Object.keys(item));
});
```

Comment: That worked, but came with duplications, any way to avoid that? (Still marked your answer as correct.)

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array